# Display fatal/notice errors in browser

Tags: hhvm

Well I just started with hhvm/hack. But I wanted to display the errors to the browser but didnot got it working.

I set the ini settings as followed

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

According to a var_dump of `ini_get` the values were set to

```
string(5) "32767"
string(1) "1"
```

But when I did

```
<?hh

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

throw new InvalidArgumentException('test');
```

When I visited the page via de browser I would just get a white screen and a 500 http header. So no explaintion of the fatal/exception error.

Would I however go via the terminal `hhvm index.php` It would show;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'test' in /var/www/public/index.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

So now the question. How does it come I don't get any messages in the browser, but do in the cli? And the second one is, how do I get it working in the browser to show messages.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086903/hhvm-fastcgi-nginx-how-to-make-it-display-fatal-errors-in-the-browser) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995847/hhvmhacklang-errors-warnings-output-into-browser). But the first, well is the same, but unanswerd. And the second is saying something about static checking. IE that an int is given etc, at least that is what I think he means.

Other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231878/hhvm-fastcgi-is-not-showing-warnings) I came by, which looked like mine, but again unanswered.

And according to the [docs](http://docs.hhvm.com//manual/en/security.errors.php) it should work I guess.

Reading more on the docs I came accross

*Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with function ini_set()), it won't have any affect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.*

So I thought well an Exception is a fatal error so I just did `$test = $bar + 1;`

This let in the cli to

```
Notice: Undefined variable: bar in /var/www/public/index.php on line 8
int(1)
```

Again in the browser

```
int(1)
```

So I don't get notices either.

When I restart hhvm `service hhvm restart` I also get the error message `Log file not specified under daemon mode.` don't know if it has anything to do with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it took me some searching but finally found the answer, [see this github post](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2571). It can't however display fatal errors. But notices are displayed

So I wrote my own error handler; it is not complete but does the job for now.

*Warning, no check for ini `display_errors`*

```
set_error_handler(function ($errorNumber, $message, $errfile, $errline) {
    switch ($errorNumber) {
        case E_ERROR :
            $errorLevel = 'Error';
            break;

        case E_WARNING :
            $errorLevel = 'Warning';
            break;

        case E_NOTICE :
            $errorLevel = 'Notice';
            break;

        default :
            $errorLevel = 'Undefined';
    }

    echo '<br/><b>' . $errorLevel . '</b>: ' . $message . ' in <b>'.$errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b><br/>';
});
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful. Worked for me to get a PHP Notice to display in HHVM.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to fall back to php when hhvm fails. Pretty simple to do that - https://bjornjohansen.no/hhvm-with-fallback-to-php. I understand you can attach php fallback per error code (like 404). So isn't it possible to fall back to php server that shows a page which loads the hhvm error log?